# Unity transform.Rotate below 0 degree not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Unity's `transform.Rotate` below 0 degree not working and I want the rotation to be smooth.

```
float rotX = transform.rotation.x;
float rotY = transform.rotation.y;
float rotZ = transform.rotation.z;

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
{
    gameObject.transform.Rotate(rotX, rotY + Time.deltaTime, rotZ, Space.Self);

}


if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
{
    gameObject.transform.Rotate(rotX, -(rotY + Time.deltaTime ), rotZ, Space.Self);

}
```

I tried multiple methods but none of them seems to work. My `gameObject` rotates(in Y-axis) fine from 0 to 275 degrees. But when I force to rotate it even further; more than 275 degrees. It starts to rotate from -90 to 0 degrees.

And when I forced it to rotate(in Y-axis) below zero degree. gameObject rotates in X-axis.

Comment: Which would be efficient.   If you rotate in one frame all that way. Why is it an issue?

Answer (score 0):

First of all `transform.rotation` is a [**`Quaternion`**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html)! It has nothing to do with **euler angles** and doesn't have 3 but rather **4** components `x`, `y`, `z`, `w` which move in ranges `-1` to `1`. See [`Quaternion`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion)

---

Further, [`Rotate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) does not **set** a final rotation but rather from the **current** rotation rotates by the given **euler** angles.

---

=> What you want to do is rather e.g.

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
{
    transform.Rotate(0, Time.deltaTime, 0);
}

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
{
    transform.Rotate(0, -Time.deltaTime, 0);
}
```

Note though that rotating `1° per second` maybe is a bit slow .. you probably want to give that a multiplier

```
[SerializeField] private float anglePerSecond = 45f;
```

and

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
{
    transform.Rotate(0, anglePerSecond * Time.deltaTime, 0);
}

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
{
    transform.Rotate(0, -anglePerSecond * Time.deltaTime, 0);
}
```